# Webfont is not displaying on Firefox when the website is hosted on final server

Tags: firefox, font-face

I have a very strange problem with webfonts and firefox.

I made a website with DIN webfont as a font-face, and it is displayed perfectly well in all the browsers, when the website is hosted on my personal server: 
http://daviddarx.com/stuffs/work/pozzo/04/

But, since we transfered the website on final servers, the webfont isn't displayed anymore in firefox (mac version), while it still is ok in other browsers: 
http://pozzo.ch/

Do you have any idea what the problem could be?
I can't figure it out, cause it's working fine locally and on my server. Also do I think that the problem may come from the final server configurations, or urls, or anything else. 
But I haven't any knowledges in these technical fields.

Comment: Hum, I just noticed that the problem doesn't appear if we visit the website at www.pozzo.ch, instead of pozzo.ch! Is that a clue?

Comment: I just resolved this bug by redirecting via htaccess the user that goes on http://pozzo.ch to http://www.pozzo.ch!
Quick and easy, even if not that optimal.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this line `src:url("../fonts/din_regular.eot?#iefix")` on your font-face makes trouble on firefox.

try to remove the "#", so write this line like this: `src:url("../fonts/din_regular.eot?iefix")`

Comment: I tried, but it didn't change anything! :(
Thank you for your answer